# 2 same algorithms for door in an infinite wall with different time complexity

Tags: algorithm

First time complexity analysis is given here

[Door in an infinite wall algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26220456/door-in-an-infinite-wall-algorithm)

My question is, we can rewrite the exact same algorithm differently and get it to be `O(n^2)`, but why?

If `n=2^k`, then at worst case we would have to walk `2^(2k+1)` steps by moving the exact same way as in the above algorithm. After some algebra that becomes `8*(2^(k-1))^2` which is less than `8*(n^2)`. Therefore `O(n^2)`.

How can the same algorithm have two different time complexities?

Comment: After some algebra that becomes 8*(2^(k-1))^2... What is this 'some algebra'? I think you got confused in the exponent math here. Since in your case 2^(2k+1) = 2*n which is still O(n)

Comment: I did this. 2^(2k+1)=2.2^(2k) = 2.(2^k)^2=2.(2.2^(k-1))^2=8(2^(k-1))^2

Comment: "How can the same algorithm have two different time complexities?": that doesn't occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is in this claim:

> ...we would have to walk `2^(2k+1)` steps

This is not true. It seems you wrongly copied this formula:

```
2 x 2^(k-1)
```

Nowhere in the [referenced question or answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26220456/door-in-an-infinite-wall-algorithm) does *k* occur with a coefficient different from 1, and there is no reason why one would need to introduce 2 for it to get *2k*.

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake. Thanks for clearing that up. I thought that by moving  one step to the left and from there 2 steps to the right and from there 4 steps to the left, and from there 8 steps to the right etc, you cover the wall in the same way.